# Magento2 SOAP Sorting error

Tags: magento2, api, soap, sorting, soap-api-v2

I'm trying to use soap API. Answer contains : The sort order has to be specified as %1 for ascending order or %2 for descending order. What i'm doing wrong?
request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:def="http://xxx/Magento-2-0-2-0-ce/soap/default?services=salesOrderRepositoryV1">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <def:salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListRequest>
         <searchCriteria>
            <filterGroups>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <filters>
                     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                     <item>
                        <field>*</field>
                        <value>*</value>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <conditionType>?</conditionType>
                     </item>
                  </filters>
               </item>
            </filterGroups>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <sortOrders>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <item>
                  <field>Name</field>
                  <direction>%1</direction>
               </item>
            </sortOrders>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <pageSize>10</pageSize><currentPage>0</currentPage>
            <!--Optional:-->

         </searchCriteria>
      </def:salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

response:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">The sort order has to be specified as %1 for ascending order or %2 for descending order.</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Looks like bug in magento response. According to sources instead of %1 and %2 i should be ASC and DESC.
       `code  'The sort order has to be specified as %1 for ascending order or %2 for descending order.',]
                [SortOrder::SORT_ASC, SortOrder::SORT_DESC] ` 
I have replaced %1 to ASC in my request, but it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error i had removed this filter

```
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
             <item>
                <field>*</field>
                <value>*</value>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <conditionType>?</conditionType>
             </item>
```